# mv instruction as part of Maven build

Tags: maven, command-line

As part of my maven build, i'd like to take the target and

```
mv current_target_snapshot_123 current_target
```

How can this be done please?

Comment: Can you give a little bit more details why you like to do that? Furthermore current_target_snapshot_123 looks a bit strange, cause i would expect to have current_target_123_snapshot ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two solutions that I am aware of:

1. Maven Antrun Plugin (see nwinkler's answer)
2. [GMaven](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GMAVEN/) Plugin with an embedded Groovy Script

   ```
   <plugin>
       <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
       <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
       <executions>
           <execution>
               <phase>generate-resources</phase>
               <goals>
                   <goal>execute</goal>
               </goals>
               <configuration>
                   <source>
                   new File('somefilename').renameTo('someotherfilename');
                   </source>
               </configuration>
           </execution>
       </executions>
   </plugin>
   ```

Answer (score 3):

I would use a combination of the following:

- Maven Antrun plugin: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/
- Ant Move Task: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/move.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [maven-dependency-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html) to do the copy into different location and strip the versions of the artifact.